# Return true if visitPhoneDate has value or return false if visitPhoneDate is undefind?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An object item.showVisitPhoneDate is true or false to hide or show visitPhoneDate. I want to return true if has value visitPhoneDate or return false if undefind

```
$scope.loadForms = function (forms) {
   $.each(forms, function (index, item) {
      item.showVisitPhoneDate =  item.visitPhoneDate === true ;
});
```

Comment: What does `forms` array contain?

Comment: Is `item.visitPhoneDate` expected to be a date or a boolean?

Comment: item.visitPhoneDate is date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you don't have to run the complete each loop once you know that `visitPhoneDate` is not undefined. You can try this.

```
$scope.loadForms = function (forms) {
            $.each(forms, function (index, item) {
                if (item.visitPhoneDate !== undefined) {
                  item.showVisitPhoneDate = true;
                  return;
                }
                else {
                  item.showVisitPhoneDate = false;
                }
            });
  }
```

Comment: just want to ask if is it possible to make it use ternary operator ?

Answer (score -1):

Check to see if `type` is `undefined`.

```
typeof item.visitPhoneDate !== 'undefined'
```

This will return true if `visitPhoneDate` is set (to anything), and false if not.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why you downvoted? Is my code incorrect?

Comment: Not my down vote, but that's equivalent to `typeof item.visitPhoneDate != 'undefined'`.